# ffmpeg, create video out of 2 images and add music

Tags: ffmpeg

So, I need to make a video out of 2 images, and later add music.

This is the instruction I found: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow

I tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i ffmpeg_input.txt -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

The `ffmpeg_input.txt` contains this:

```
file 'wow.jpg'
duration 219
file 'wow2.jpg'
duration 1
file 'wow2.jpg'
```

This kinda works, but when I try to add music, I get a bugged video: when I open it, it starts playing with a correct size and duration, but no video or audio is heard. I hear the audio after I seek closer to the end and then seek back,

This is how I convert .wav to .m4a:

```
ffmpeg -i _done.wav -c:a aac -b:a 160k _done.m4a
```

And this is how I merge video and audio together:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i _done.m4a -c copy output_final.mp4
```

I probably should try sony vegas or such already.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add everything in one go:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i ffmpeg_input.txt \
-i _done.wav -c:a aac -b:a 160k \
-vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p \
output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks. Still something wrong with the video though. It's as if the video turns out to be very low fps, and this somehow makes my player bug out.

Comment: That's the variable frame rate which might be incompatible with some players. Does it work in `ffplay`?

Comment: Yes. Only seeking doesn't work, but it plays fine.

Comment: You could re-convert into CFR by `ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -r 30 -crf 18 -c:a copy output2.mp4`, but note that this will re-encode and therefore degrade video quality a little. I chose CRF 18, but you can pick any other sane value: https://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html